# how can send email for reseting password

Tags: flutter, email, smtp

I want to set a Screen in my app for sending an email for resetting password. I can send an Email from firebase but I do not know how  I can write codes when user click on 'reset password button' automatically a confirming email send for user. Also I read some text about smtp but I could not understand what I should do , please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send reset password email using this code

```dart
 sendEmail() async {
    try {
      showLoader(context);
      String emailAddress = "example@gmail.com";  // email address
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: emailAddress);
      
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
     
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can use it without having smtp?

Comment: The code above makes a request of FirebaseAuth to send an email with a password reset, so if you're using FirebaseAuth for authentication, this should work for you -- your app won't actually send the email because it doesn't have to.  And BTW, when the user gets the email and clicks on the embedded link, FirebaseAuth takes care of that for you too.

Comment: @NegarTavakol yes it can work without smtp in this you can use of FirebaseAuth just.